# How to set multiple values in Set-Alias in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, terminal

I have set this in my PowerShell profile

```
Set-Alias vim nvim
Set-Alias gfg python.exe main.py
```

the "gfg" alias does not work, I have also tried to do this

```
Set-Alias -Name gfg -Value python.exe main.py
```

but this does not works as well

Here is the error message :

```
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'main.py'.
```

I want a single alias to execute my python script

Thank you.

Comment: You need to place it in a function instead, due to how `Set-Alias` works.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala can you provide examples, resources. Thanks

Comment: @anindiangeek `function gfg { & python.exe main.py }`

Comment: an alias in powershell is just a replacement for the cmdlet so if you have parameters then you must use a function. See [Quick start "complex" command from within PowerShell](https://superuser.com/q/1595732/241386). Just read [about_Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.2)